# Custom control binding query

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am creating a custom control by inheriting from ContentControl. Below is the XAML code present in Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="YellowGreen"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="/Themes/icon.png"></Setter>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{TemplateBinding IconSource}" Stretch="None"></Image>

                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Grid.Column="1">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentContainer" 
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>

    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In my  application , i have used the custom control in this way:

```
    <mycontrol:MyCustomControl Height="100" Width="400" 
                               Foreground="Red"
                               IconSource="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png">
        <mycontrol:MyCustomControl.Content>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock  Text="Some Text Content Here"/>
                <Button Content="Test Button" Foreground="Pink" Background="Black"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </mycontrol:MyCustomControl.Content>
    </mycontrol:MyCustomControl>
```

I don't understand **how & why** does the textblock text in stackpanel gets red color. Can someone explain me how and why it is happening in simple words ?

here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of

```
<mycontrol:MyCustomControl Height="100" Width="400" 
                           Foreground="Red"
                           IconSource="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png">
```

`Foreground` is then inherited down the elements tree into your `StackPanel`, `TextBlock` and `Button`, but because the `Button` has `Foreground` set explicitly it's not red.